# std::list<shared_ptr<Shape*>> pLShape?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, stdlist

I have a question and that is that in List, vector and/or shared_ptr/unique_ptr you can pass classes as objects as well as pointers.
I do not understand now when one would use e.g shared_ptr<Shape*> pShape;?
When does it make sense to pass e.g. in the case the class Shape as a pointer and when not?

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <crtdbg.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include "CAD_Drawing.h" 


...

void CAD::CAD_Drawing::vDrawIt(void)
{
    for (auto it : CAD::CAD_Drawing::setShapes_)
    {
        it->vDraw();

    }
}
void CAD::CAD_Drawing::vAddShape(std::shared_ptr<Shape> pShape)
{
    setShapes_.insert(pShape);
    
}

void CAD::CAD_Drawing::vRemoveShape(std::shared_ptr<Shape> pShape)
{
    setShapes_.erase(pShape);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't mention `shared_ptr<Shape*>`. `shared_ptr<Shape>` is a class type that *behaves like* `Shape*` in many ways, but also carries ownership

Comment: presumably `Shape` is a class with virtual member functions. If you want to pass *any subclass* of `Shape` and use the overridden member(s), it must be by pointer or reference. And if any of the member functions are pure virtual, you *can't* pass `Shape` by value.

Comment: "...in List, vector and/or shared_ptr/unique_ptr you can pass classes as objects as well as pointers." -- I honestly can't make sense of this. You have been trying to put too much info into a single sentence, rendering it it unreadable. Just one question, what is the meaning of "pass classes" there?

Comment: The purpose of `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` is to automatically manage specific ownership principles instead of doing it by hand. `shared_ptr<T>` represents a shared object of type `T` that gets destroyed when it has no owners. A *pointer* with shared ownership, like `shared_ptr<Shape*>`, makes very little sense.

Comment: A template (such as `std::vector`) can have type parameters. The type arguments you pass can be anything that supports the required operations, which often includes arithmetic and pointer types. You aren't passing an *object* to a template type parameter. Pronounce `std::vector<int>` as "(standard) vector of int", as a shorthand for "the specialisation of the (standard) vector class template for the type int (and other defaulted parameters)"